# Binding To ModelContainer()

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net-entity-data-model

i"m trying to bind a datagrid object in WinForm to ModelContainer.

i have 2 tables for the examples Students and City. each entity has a property in the ModelContainter.

Moreover, i in debug mode , each entity has a Result View property which stores the whole entity(table) data.

how can i bind it to the datagrid?

this is my code :

```
// this is the model container from my model.edmx
ModelContainer a = new ModelContainer(); 

datagridview1.DataSource = a;
```

but i cant find a way to declare the data member.

thanks for the helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your databinding should go to the tables in the container, e.g.

```
datagridview1.DataSource = a.Students;
```